# Jquery selected select by value

Tags: jquery, html, select

i want to add a selected, if my Model.StartYear is the same as the value of the option.

my select:

```
<select name="year" class="form-control holidaySelect">
                <option value="2015">2015/2016</option>
                <option value="2016">2016/2017</option>
                <option value="2017">2017/2018</option>
                <option value="2018">2018/2019</option>
                <option value="2019">2019/2020</option>
            </select>
```

my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = @Model.StartYear;
    $(".holidaySelect option").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == num) { // EDITED THIS LINE
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Model.StartYear contains the selected value of the option. 
So that should be matched to the option.

Can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can directly use [`.val(value)`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".holidaySelect").val(@Model.StartYear)
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".holidaySelect").val(2018)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="year" class="form-control holidaySelect">
  <option value="2015">2015/2016</option>
  <option value="2016">2016/2017</option>
  <option value="2017">2017/2018</option>
  <option value="2018">2018/2019</option>
  <option value="2019">2019/2020</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how should this be implemented ?

Comment: I have no idea where to input that, or where to view it..  but model.startyear contains forexample " 2016 "

Comment: UserHoliday:234 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @andrelange91 You need to add jQuery script like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: never mind. Changed the whole thing, and did it in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when @Model.StartYear is not empty value.
Here you can see working fiddle for 2017 value

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var num = 2017;
    $(".holidaySelect option").each(function (key) {
        if ($(this).val() == num) { // EDITED THIS LINE
            $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="year" class="form-control holidaySelect">
                <option value="2015">2015/2016</option>
                <option value="2016">2016/2017</option>
                <option value="2017">2017/2018</option>
                <option value="2018">2018/2019</option>
                <option value="2019">2019/2020</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Model.startYear will always have a value. if the user have not chosen a value in select, it will be set to the current year.